# The distribution of the inner product of a random complex normal vector.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Good day! I would like to find the distribution of the inner product of a random complex normal vector with:

- some constant vector;
- random gaussian vector.

Let's assume a vector $\vec{z}$ which has a complex normal distribution with location parameter $\mu$, covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ and the relation matrix $\mathbf{C}$:
$$\vec{z}=\{\Re{\vec{z}},\Im{\vec{z}}\}^{T}=\{z_1,z_2\ldots z_n\}^{T}\sim \mathit{CN}(\mu_{\vec{z}},
\mathbf{\Gamma},\mathbf{C})$$
So the [pdf of $\vec{z}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution#Density_function) is:
$$w_{\vec{z}}(z_1,z_2\ldots z_n)= \frac{1}{\pi^k\sqrt{\det(\mathbf{\Gamma})\det(\mathbf{\Gamma}-\mathbf{C^{H}}\mathbf{\Gamma^{-1}}\mathbf{C})}}\times\\ \times \exp\!\left[\!-\frac12 \begin{pmatrix}
(\vec{z}-\mu_{\vec{z}})^{\ast}\!\!\!&\!\!\!(\vec{z}-\mu_{\vec{z}})\end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{\Gamma}&\mathbf{C}\\\mathbf{C^{H}}&\mathbf{\Gamma}^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}^{\!\!-1}\! \!\!                                 \begin{pmatrix} \vec{z}-\mu_{\vec{z}} \\ \vec{z}^{\ast}-\mu_{\vec{z}}^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}
\right] $$
and a complex constant vector $\vec{a}=\{\Re{\vec{a}},\Im{\vec{a}}\}^{T}=\{a_1,a_2\ldots a_n\}^{T}$.

I'd like to find the joint distribution of $(\Re{U},\Im{U})$ where $U=\vec{z}.\vec{a}^{\mathbf{H}}$

**My attempt.**

First I can form a matrix $\mathbf{A}=\text{diag}\{\vec{a}^{\mathbf{H}}\}$ and using the property that
$$Z\ \sim\ \mathit{CN}(\mu,\,\mathbf{\Gamma},\, \mathbf{C}) \quad\Rightarrow\quad AZ+b\ \sim\ \mathit{CN}(A\mu+b,\, A\mathbf{\Gamma} A^{\mathbf{H}},\, A\mathbf{C}A^{\mathbf{T}}) $$
and rearranging $U=\vec{z}.\vec{a}^{\mathbf{H}}$ as $U=\mathrm{tr}\left(\mathbf{A}\vec{z}\right)$ I can say that $\mathbf{A}\vec{z}\sim \mathit{CN}(\mathbf{A}\mu_{\vec{z}},\, \mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Gamma} \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{H}},\, \mathbf{A}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{T}})$.
Then I tried to rewrite covariance matrix of $\mathbf{A}\vec{z}$ as:
$$    \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Gamma} \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{H}}&\mathbf{A}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{T}}\\(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{T}})^{\mathbf{H}}&(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Gamma} \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{H}})^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{A}&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{A}^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{\Gamma}&\mathbf{C}\\\mathbf{C^{H}}&\mathbf{\Gamma}^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{A}^{\ast}&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{A}\end{pmatrix}
$$
And since $\mathbf{A}$ is diagonal
$$\det{\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Gamma} \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{H}}&\mathbf{A}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{T}}\\(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{T}})^{\mathbf{H}}&(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Gamma} \mathbf{A}^{\mathbf{H}})^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}}=\det{\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{\Gamma}&\mathbf{C}\\\mathbf{C^{H}}&\mathbf{\Gamma}^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}}\prod^n_{i=1}|a_i|^4$$
So the pdf of $\mathbf{A}\vec{z}$ would look like:
$$
w_{\mathbf{A}\vec{z}}(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n)= \frac{1}{\pi^k\sqrt{\det{\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{\Gamma}&\mathbf{C}\\\mathbf{C^{H}}&\mathbf{\Gamma}^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}}}\prod^n_{i=1}|a_i|^2 }\times\\ \!\!\times \!\!\exp\!\left[\!-\frac12 \begin{pmatrix}
(\vec{x}-\mathbf{A}\mu_{\vec{z}})^{\ast}\!\!\!&\!\!\!(\vec{x}-\mathbf{A}\mu_{\vec{z}}\! )\end{pmatrix}
   \!\!\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{A^{-1}}&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{A^{-1}}^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}\! \!\!\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{\Gamma}&\mathbf{C}\\\mathbf{C^{H}}&\mathbf{\Gamma}^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}^{\!\!-1}\! \!\!\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{A^{-1}}^{\ast}&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{A^{-1}}\end{pmatrix}\! \!\!                                 \begin{pmatrix} \vec{x}-\mathbf{A}\mu_{\vec{z}} \\ \vec{x}^{\ast}-\mathbf{A}^{\ast}\mu_{\vec{z}}^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}\! \!\!
\right] 
$$
**UPDATE**

 Using the notation of augmented matrices and vectors I can put it in a different form.
Let's call $$\mathbf{\alpha}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{A}^{\ast}&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{A}\end{pmatrix}, \ \mathbf{\alpha^{-1}}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{A^{-1}}^{\ast}&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}&\mathbf{A^{-1}}\end{pmatrix}, \ \mathbf{R}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{\Gamma}&\mathbf{C}\\\mathbf{C^{H}}&\mathbf{\Gamma}^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}, \ \underline{\vec{x}}=\begin{pmatrix} \vec{x}\\ \vec{x}^{\ast}\end{pmatrix}$$
Then the pdf can be rewritten as
$$
w_{\mathbf{A}\vec{z}}(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n)= \frac{1}{\pi^{k}\prod^n_{i=1}|a_i|^{2}\sqrt{\det{\mathbf{R}}}}\exp\!\left[\!-\frac12 
(\underline{\vec{x}}-\mathbf{\alpha}\underline{\mu_{\vec{z}}})^{\mathbf{H}}
   \mathbf{\alpha^{-H}}
\mathbf{R}^{\!\!-1}\mathbf{\alpha^{-1}} (\underline{\vec{x}}-\mathbf{\alpha}\underline{\mu_{\vec{z}}})
\right] 
$$
then multiplying matrices inside the exponent I get
$$
w_{\mathbf{A}\vec{z}}(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n)= \frac{1}{\pi^{k}\prod^n_{i=1}|a_i|^{2}\sqrt{\det{\mathbf{R}}}}\exp\!\left[\!-\frac12 
(\mathbf{\alpha^{-1}}\underline{\vec{x}}-\underline{\mu_{\vec{z}}})^{\mathbf{H}}
  \mathbf{R}^{\!\!-1}(\mathbf{\alpha^{-1}}\underline{\vec{x}}-\underline{\mu_{\vec{z}}})
\right] \!\!\!\tag{1}
$$

But next I should find the distribution of the  sum of elements of $\mathbf{A}\vec{z}$ and here I'm stuck.



In the second case one can set $\vec{a}$ to be gaussian with augmented mean vector $\underline{\mu_{\vec{a}}}$ and augmented covariance matrix $\mathbf{R_a}$ and pdf
$$w_{\vec{a}}(a_1,a_2\ldots a_n)= \frac{1}{\pi^{k}\sqrt{\det{\mathbf{R_a}}}}\exp\!\left[\!-\frac12 
(\underline{\vec{a}}-\underline{\mu_{\vec{a}}})^{\mathbf{H}}
  \mathbf{R_a}^{\!\!-1}(\underline{\vec{a}}-\underline{\mu_{\vec{a}}})
\right] $$
Then one can treat $(1)$ as the conditional distribution of $\mathbf{A}\vec{z}$ given $\vec{a}$, so the unconditional distibution would be 
$$
w_{\mathbf{A}\vec{z}}(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n)=\int w_{\mathbf{A}\vec{z}|\vec{a}}(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n|\vec{a})w_{\vec{a}}(a_1,a_2\ldots a_n)\mathrm{d \vec{a}}$$
Which (up to the scale factor) will look like
$$
w_{\mathbf{A}\vec{z}}(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n)\!\!\propto \!\!\int \!
\!\frac{1}{\prod^n_{i=1}|a_i|^{2}} 
\!\exp\!\left[\!-\!\frac{(\mathbf{\alpha^{-1}}\underline{\vec{x}}\!-\!\underline{\mu_{\vec{z}}})^{\mathbf{H}}
  \mathbf{R}^{\!\!-1}(\!\mathbf{\alpha^{-1}}\!\underline{\vec{x}}\!-\!\underline{\mu_{\vec{z}}}\!)\!+\!
(\!\underline{\vec{a}}\!-\!\underline{\mu_{\vec{a}}})^{\mathbf{H}}
  \mathbf{R_a}^{\!\!-1}(\!\underline{\vec{a}}\!-\!\underline{\mu_{\vec{a}}}\!)}{2}
\right]\!
\mathrm{d \!\vec{a}} 
$$
It is not clear to me how to cope with this integral (especially since \vec{a} is complex then it should be treated as some contour integral or not?)


So my questions are:

1. How to complete the trace operation in $(1)$ in order to get inner product with a constant vector?
2. How to perform integration in the last equation in order to get inner product with a gaussian vector?